# List items not starting from beginning

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an unordered list, and I'm trying to render some li elements within it. However, the first element doesn't start rendering from the very beginning of the list, and there is a slight margin. How do I resolve this, and why is it happening?

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <ul
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '75%',
        height: '5%',
        left: '12.5%',
        top: '25%',
        'list-style-type': 'none',
        'background-color': '#f8d7d7'
      }}
    >
      <li
        style={{
          width: '20%',
          float: 'left',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      />
      <li
        style={{
          width: '20%',
          float: 'left',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      />
      <li
        style={{
          width: '20%',
          float: 'left',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      />
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/zm35q7xv/1/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons as to why this is happening:

1. Your `<ul>` has `position` set to `absolute` and with **left 12%** which adds the space on left.
2. `<ul>` also has its own padding, which again adds some space at the beginning - you will have to change it as per your requirements.

Comment: is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <ul
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        paddingLeft: '0px',
        width: '75%',
        height: '5%',
        left: '12.5%',
        top: '25%',
        'list-style-type': 'none',
        'background-color': '#f8d7d7'
      }}
    >
      <li
        style={{
          width: '20%',
          float: 'left',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      >list item 1 </li>
      <li
        style={{
          width: '20%',
          float: 'left',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      >list item 2 </li>
      <li
        style={{
          width: '20%',
          float: 'left',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      >list item 3 </li>
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```